# Subspace Inherits Discrete Topology

Tags: general-topology

I have a line in the plane $\mathbb{R}_\ell \times \mathbb{R}_\ell$, where the $\ell$ denotes the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with the lower limit topology, and I am asked to describe the topology $L$ inherits as a subspace.

I am currently working on the last case and having trouble with this. In this case, I am assuming that $L$ has a negative slope. A typical basis element of $\mathbb{R}_\ell \times \mathbb{R}_\ell$ has the form $B= [a,b) \times [c,d)$. If $L$ has negative slope, it could either intersect at the rectangles bottom left-corner, the point $(a,c)$ in the plane, or it does not intersect at that point.

Regarding the former case, it is clear that a basis element for the subspace topology on $L$ is $B \cap L = \{(a,c)\}$, where $(a,c)$ is an arbitrary point. Hence, the collection of these sets is a basis for the discrete topology on $L$.

Regarding the latter case, I am having a little difficulty. Continuing with our assumption that $L$ has a negative slope, it is clear that $B \cap L = \{(x,mx+b) ~|~ x \in [a,q]\}$, where we let $(a,t)$ and $(q,s)$ are the intersection points of the $L$ with the two edges of the rectangle. I know sets of the form $[a,b]$ form a basis for the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$, so my guess is that the subspace topology on $L$ is, again, the discrete topology. However, I am having difficulty showing this.

Comment: Given a point on the line, can you find an open set in $\mathbb{R}_{\ell} \times\mathbb{R}_{\ell}$ so that the singleton set containing the point is exactly the intersection of the open set with the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For negatively sloped lines, the inherited topology is indeed the discrete topology, because every singleton is open in $L$. Note that we have the freedom to choose any basis element of $\mathbb R_\ell \times \mathbb R_\ell$ that is convenient for us to use when intersecting with $L$. Indeed, for any point $a \times c \in L$, we have that:
$$
\{a \times c \} = L \cap ([a, a + 1) \times [c, c + 1))
$$
Since $[a, a + 1) \times [c, c + 1)$ is open in $\mathbb R_\ell \times \mathbb R_\ell$, it follows that $\{a \times c \}$ is open in $L$, as desired.

Comment: Why do we have the freedom to choose a basis of $\mathbb{R}_\ell^2$ when finding an arbitrary basis element for the topology on $L$?

Comment: @user193319: Adriano didn’t choose a base for the topology; he simply chose a particular open set in $\Bbb R_\ell^2$. That open set happens to be an element of the natural base for the topology of $\Bbb R_\ell^2$, but that fact isn’t important; what’s important is that the set is open and that its intersection with $L$ is the singleton $\{\langle a,c\rangle\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, so basis elements of the subspace are of the form $B \cap L$, where $B$ is some basis element of the "bigger space." So, the point is that I can choose $B$ to find out what some of the basis elements of $L$ look like, and all that I need is that some of them look like $\{a \times c\}$, where $a \times c$ is an arbitrary point on $L$, in order to conclude that subspace topology is the discrete topology?

Comment: @adriano Wouldn't the basic element $[a,a) \times [b,b)$ work? If so, wouldn't that suggest that the lower limit topology and discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ are the same? Is that correct?

Comment: In other words, is $[a,a)$ a basic element of the lower limit topology?

Comment: Unfortunately, $[a, a) = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid a \leq x < a\} = \varnothing$.

Comment: @user193319: There’s really no need to consider bases at all, for $\Bbb R_\ell$, for $\Bbb R_\ell^2$, or for $L$. You know that $[a,a+1)$ and $[b,b+1)$ are open sets in $\Bbb R_\ell$, so you know that $[a,a+1)\times[b,b+1)$ is open in $\Bbb R_\ell^2$. Its intersection with $L$ is $\{\langle a,b\rangle\}$, so by definition $\{\langle a,b\rangle\}$ is an open set in the relative topology on $L$. Thus, every point of $L$ is an isolated point, so every subset of $L$ is open in the relative topology, and the relative topology is therefore discrete.